# How to write postgres Query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hi I am Trying to write the postgres query for the rails. How to do that. Can any one tell

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
  avg(company_ratings.satisfaction+ 
  company_ratings.work_environment+ 
  company_ratings.cd+
  company_ratings.flexibility
  )as averageall
FROM 
  public.company_ratings
WHERE 
  company_ratings.company_id = company_ratings.id;
```

Hi As per your Suggestion and as per the guide I have query as

```
ratings.average('satisfaction+ work_environment+cd+flexibility')
```

Syntax

```
Client.average("orders_count")
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "satisfaction" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG(satisfaction+ work_environment+cd+flexi...
                   ^
: SELECT AVG(satisfaction+ work_environment+cd+flexibility) AS avg_id FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."company_id" = $1
```

So I could not understand my error.As i am learning the rails

Comment: Go to google, type "rails guides query interface" and press enter.

Comment: Does the query error?  Or what?

Comment: Hi as per your suggestions I tried but I am getting the following error.

Answer (score 2):

to help the other I am posting this as my answer.
I am getting the above error because I haven't used correct model name of my ratings.

As the correct one was

```
CompanyRating.average('satisfaction+ work_environment+cd+flexibility')
```

So Please remember that always model name starts with Capital letter and if your are using editors it differentiate the modelname. This is mainly for newbies.